# Attachments order with own SQL query

Tags: wordpress

I'm using a second db for a part of my Wordpress. I want to loop the attachments, and I want to attachments to be order as they are order in the admin list.

How do I add "order by" in below SQL for the Attachments? The menu_order itself is empty, I guess I need some kind of join?

```
$attach = $newdb->get_results( "SELECT ID,guid FROM pm_posts where post_type ='attachment' AND post_parent = $post_id");
```

Attachments is handle by plugin: https://github.com/jchristopher/attachments
Where sorting is done manually, but I can't find where the sorting data is stored in the db, why I can't just use the normal table "menu_order" as this all say 0.

Comment: So - how do you perceive that they are ordered in the admin list? I'm guessing it's by date, newest to oldest, yes? Then just add `ORDER BY post_date DESC`, and you're done.

Comment: Sorry, my question lacked of information. Using a plugin called Attachments, and this seems to store the order somewhere else than normal "menu_order" why I can't just do a normal order by. Please check updated main question